# How to call function through onclick when JS is loaded through System.js

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, typescript, systemjs

I'm have an typescript file in my MVC project that has gotten quite large. I want to break it up use System.js to load the files.

I have included the system.js reference within my _Layout.cshtml view.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/system.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        System.import("Scripts/main.js");
    });
</script>
```

My main.ts file has a function that loads an item.

```
function load(id: string): void
{
    // Stuff
}
```

In my Index.cshtml view I have a div that calls the function when it's clicked.

```
<div onclick="load('@item.Id')"></div>
```

But everytime I click on the div I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):41)
```

Looking at the network traffic I can see that main.js is loaded by system.js. But for some reason the functions cannot be accessed via the HTML. Am I doing the something in the wrong spot? Or is there a specific way I need to setup my typescript file to call the function?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure javascript is loaded before the call for your JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div onclick="load('@item.Id')"></div>` This old-school-pure-html way of binding event listener requires `load` to be a global scope function.

System.js import your `main.js`, but it kinda scopes it up in a closure I guess. `load` is no longer accessible in global scope, thus the bug.